# Can't install nvidia driver on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

I've installed Windows 10. Then I tried to install the driver for my nvidia card (gtx 750) but it failed. At first restart the resolution became really high (1920x1080) so it seemed like the driver was installed successfully. Then suddenly black screen. I've restarted the computer and it went back to 1024x768 and I can't change it. I've tried reinstalling the driver, even tried different versions but with no success.

Comment: You indicated it failed.  This means there is a log file, which indicates the failure, we need the failure and the log file.  Based on what you describe it sounds like you installed the faulty Windows 10 Nvidia driver by accident.  Be sure you have the fixed version before you attempt to install it again.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to provide that. I'll do that ASAP.

Comment: This is a long-standing problem and is not specific to Windows 10. There are plenty of solutions on Google, most of which include using a driver cleaner and reinstalling the driver:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nvidia+driver+black+screen

Comment: downloading the driver for windows 10 from nvidia worked for me.

Comment: Could you provide the link where you downloaded it from?

Comment: I can't even install GeForce Experience and Nvidia doesn't seem to have any Windows 10 drivers for 780 Ti. Latest one for 8.1 was added today.

Comment: When you download from nvidia you get an installer which unzips to this location (it asks you where) by default `C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\372.70\Win10_64\International`.  Go to that folder, and right click the setup > `Run as Administrator`.  Solved my problem. Running the download as Administrator alone does not install!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I did was removed everything nvidia related from my computer and I've let Windows find a driver for me. That worked and good enough for me.

Comment: To clarify this answer: Search for 'Device Manager' underneath the 'Search' bar and click to open it. Once the Device Manager window opens, click the drop down arrow next to 'Display Adapaters' or 'Other Devices' to find your graphics card. Right click the item and choose 'Update Driver Software' and choose the first option - 'Have Windows search online'.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter your solution didn't work for me (W10 insisted on that I already had the most updated drivers...)

Following @Journeyman's advice I downloaded the drivers from nvidia official web page. It's important to add here that after installing and rebooting I had to create a personalized resolution:

right click > nvidia control panel > Screen > change resolution > personalize...> create personalized resolution

There I chose 1280x1024 at 60Hz for 32 bits
AND
Under Synchronization I chose GTF (the "automatic" didn't work)

Now I have this other resolution rather than the 1024x768